# Announce Core MIDI virtual port via Bonjour on OS X

Tags: ios, macos, bonjour, coremidi

I wrote an iOS app a while ago which was receiving and sending MIDI commands over the network.
All I needed to do was to create a virtual MIDI port which then showed up as connectable node in Audio-MIDI Setup of all Macs on the local network automatically.
Meaning that it was automatically advertised as a service via Bonjour.

I now tried to do the same on OS X but I unfortunately my virtual MIDI port won't show up on the network computer's Audio-MIDI Setup. 
Can anyone give me a hint on how to setup a Bonjour service so that my virtual MIDI port is published across the network?

I tried the CocoaEcho example project and modified the code to announce a NSNetService like so:

```
[[NSNetService alloc] initWithDomain:@"local"
                                type:@"_apple-midi._udp."
                                name:@"" port:(int) self.port];
```

and announcing the service seems to work (it shows up in Audio-MIDI Setup).
However, I don't know how to proceed from here as connecting to my newly published MIDI port doesn't call any of the installed callbacks.

Thanks!

Comment: Why the down vote? Please comment what I can do to improve the question.

Comment: if you set your domain to `@""` it can work, you also missed a dot at `local.`
of course standard port for that service is udp5004 upwards. `name` should be the name of your machine without domain ending. you should have a delegate where your netservice is watched, and of course you need to publish and startMonitoring the service.